# Getting final parent in hierarchy table

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a SQL table with parent and child information like

```
child  parent 
---------------
  a      b  
  b      c
  c      d
  e      f
```

My result should be like

```
child  parent
---------------
  a      d  
  b      d
  c      d
  e      f
```

Each row should have child and its final parent in its hierarchy.

How can I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: `Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: If you use a DBMS that supports [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) you can use a recursive common table expression. Check out the solution tagged with [tag:recursive-query]

Comment: I'm using sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do using recursive CTE. This is a sample.

```
declare @tbl table(child varchar(5),  parent varchar(5))
insert @tbl values
  ('a',      'b'),  
  ('b',      'c'),
  ('c',      'd'),
  ('e',      'f')

  ;with tbl as (
  --anchor query
  --find starting level
  select parent child, parent parent, 0 lvl
  from @tbl t
  where parent not in (select child from @tbl)
  union all
  --recursive query
  select t.child, tbl.parent, lvl+1 --keep top level parent
  from @tbl t
  inner join tbl on t.parent=tbl.child --go up the tree to previous level
  )
  --filter final results
  select child,parent from tbl
  where lvl>0 --lvl 0 is fake level
  order by child
```